# Why excel rounded but still shows more than 2 decimal points

Tags: excel

I have a set of numbers that was rounded of to 2. When I sum a range, i ended on a cell which shows 762,078.31. I copied this cell and paste value and it actually shows 762078.31. I increased decimal and it still shows 762078.3100. But on the 'formula bar' it shows as 762078.309999999.

I would like to show the calculations here but there ~359 rows. It's simple formula used as follows;  =ROUND(Q2*S2,2) and =SUM(Y2:Y359).
Anyone with an idea why this happens, do let me know.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it's happening, but you can edit the SUM cell to round as well:

```
 =ROUND(SUM(Y2:Y359),2)
```

Answer (score 0):

It could just be a rounding error in Excel. The article below gives an example where if you subtract 22.26 - 21.29 you get 0.970000000000002.

http://journalofaccountancy.com/issues/2014/mar/excel-calculation-errors.html

There are many examples where you will see Excel's precision slightly off, but as noted in the article, users find them to be insignificant.